# Google Data Studio Visualize Count of Distinct Events in Pie Chart

Tags: visualization, pie-chart, looker-studio

We have a list of tasks on the website that all users need to perform before they are able to apply for a job. Tracked by Events

I'm able to create a table by `userid` that shows all the task that were completed by that user and then I'm able to create a table that shows distinct count of all tasks they've finished.

To count the task events, I've created a new metric

```
COUNT_DISTINCT(Event Action)
```

Then using a filter to show the task I'm interested in.

**Tasks completed by User**:

| User ID | Count of Tasks Completed |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 5 | 9 |
| 6 | 9 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 9 | 4 |
| 10 | 2 |

What I'd like to do is show a pie chart that display the % of users that completed a certain number of tasks. For example 30% completed 10 tasks, 20% completed 9 tasks, etc.

Comment: I was able to use a case statement to convert the count to text, but it's still showing up in Data Studio as a "Blue" metric and not a dimension.

Comment: CASE  
       WHEN Count Distinct Events  = 11 THEN "100 %"  
       WHEN Count Distinct Events  = 10 THEN "90 %"  
       WHEN Count Distinct Events  = 9 THEN "80 %"  
       WHEN Count Distinct Events  = 8 THEN "70 %"  
       WHEN Count Distinct Events  = 7 THEN "60 %"  
       WHEN Count Distinct Events  = 6 THEN "50 %"  
    END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a while, but I finally figured this one out.

First you have to create three new metrics, one to count distinct events and one to count distinct user IDs You need a third to convert the distinct event counts into a usable metric for calculating a completion % and is based on the distinct event counts.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then I created filters to isolate the specific events I'm interested in.

Since you can't re-aggregate data or apply filters based on a custom metrics in a data source, I created two separate tables with the necessary filters in order to blend the data.

[image]

I then blended the data and created the necessary additional filter based on the event count and applied to desired blended source. In this case, I want to see all users with an ID that finished 11 tasks.

Blended table

[image]

Blended data source

[image]

The final step is divide the total number of desired events / total users to get a completion rate.

[image]

And here's the custom metric for that.

[image]

This is pretty controverted and took taking several technics from several blog sources and combining them into one work flow.